# re-evaluate custom validator directive on input change

Tags: angular, validation, angular-directive

I have a custom directive validator that uses an input to check validity. Using the original value, the validity works just fine. If I update the input, though, the validator still says the error and does not re-evaluate the value. How can I force a re-evaluation upon an update to the input?

directive:

```
export class TimeRangeValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input() maxTime;
    @Input() minTime;

    validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return CustomValidators.timeRange(this.maxTime, this.minTime)(control);
    }
}
```

When min or max time update, I would like to cause the validation to re-run so that if the new max is above the control value or the new min is below it, previous errors will not persist

**EDIT**
Based on the answer given by @Kevin Zhang (re-writing it here for clarity)

The solution:

```
export class TimeRangeValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    private _onChange?: ()=>void;
    private _maxTime;
    private _minTime;

    @Input() 
    get maxTime() { return this._maxTime}
    
    set maxTime(value) {
        this._maxTime = value;
        if(this._onChange) {
            this._onChange();
        }
    }

    @Input() 
    get minTime() { return this._minTime}
    
    set minTime(value) {
        this._minTime = value;
        if(this._onChange) {
            this._onChange();
        }
    }

    validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return CustomValidators.timeRange(this.maxTime, this.minTime)(control);
    }

    registerOnValidatorChanges(fn:()=>void): void {
        this._onChange = fn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to below code use getter/setter and register validator change fn.

```
@Directive({
  selector:
      ':not([type=checkbox])[required][formControlName],:not([type=checkbox])[required][formControl],:not([type=checkbox])[required][ngModel]',
  providers: [REQUIRED_VALIDATOR],
  host: {'[attr.required]': 'required ? "" : null'}
})
export class RequiredValidator implements Validator {
  private _required = false;
  private _onChange?: () => void;

  /**
   * @description
   * Tracks changes to the required attribute bound to this directive.
   */
  @Input()
  get required(): boolean|string {
    return this._required;
  }

  set required(value: boolean|string) {
    this._required = value != null && value !== false && `${value}` !== 'false';
    if (this._onChange) this._onChange();
  }

  /**
   * @description
   * Method that validates whether the control is empty.
   * Returns the validation result if enabled, otherwise null.
   */
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null {
    return this.required ? Validators.required(control) : null;
  }

  /**
   * @description
   * Registers a callback function to call when the validator inputs change.
   *
   * @param fn The callback function
   */
  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what the onChange function is, and how to provide it if I am using a directive?

Comment: registerOnValidatorChange is implement from Validator, so the fn is the callback function,  so once you call the onChange, it will trigger Angular to know the changes you set on template.